# Is there a way to tell Windows which disk to consider primary for the performance rating?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, performance

I have my games installed on a separate, faster drive from the OS. My CPU and RAM rate 6.6, GPU and Aero are 6.0, but my lowly primary hard disk is only 5.4. I'd like some way to see what windows "thinks" of my newer drive, if only out of pure curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. WINSAT always evaluates the primary hard disk, which is always the disk the operating system is installed on.